# Localhost don't reload php script

Tags: php, apache, phpmailer, slim

I have an script in PHP and even saving and trying to execute it in different browsers It seems like it's cached or something because every change I do, it doesn't appear live.

**EDIT 2**
I'm trying this in my server and it works fine, if I change the file, the web changes as usual. My server is running a Debian with apache2 exactly as I have locally.

**EDIT**
I tried to remove the $app->post('/send-mail', 'AppmaticController:sendMail'); and it stills working!!

Class /app/controllers/AppmaticController.php

```
namespace Appmatic\Controllers;

use Appmatic\Errors\ErrorHandler;
use Psr\Http\Message\RequestInterface;
use Psr\Http\Message\ResponseInterface;

class AppmaticController
{
    private $slimApp;

    public function __construct($app)
    {
        $this->slimApp = $app;
    }

    public function sendMail(RequestInterface $request, ResponseInterface $response, $arguments)
    {

        $name = filter_var($request->getParsedBody()['name'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
        $email = filter_var($request->getParsedBody()['email'], FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL);
        $subject = filter_var($request->getParsedBody()['subject'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
        $message = filter_var($request->getParsedBody()['message'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);

        $mail = new \PHPMailer();
        $mail->isSMTP();
        $mail->Host = 'smtp.1and1.es';
        $mail->Port = 587;
        $mail->SMTPAuth = true;
        $mail->Username = 'info@nulltilus.com';
        $mail->Password = 'pass';
        $mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';

        $mail->setFrom($email, $name);
        $mail->addAddress('info@nulltilus.com', 'Nulltilus');
        $mail->isHTML(false);

        $mail->Subject = $subject;
        $mail->Body = $message;

        if(!$mail->send()) {
            echo 'Message could not be sent.';
            echo 'Mailer Error: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo;
        } else {
            echo 'El mensaje se ha enviado';
        }

    }
}
```

/public_html/index.php

```
<?php

use Appmatic\Controllers as Controllers;
use Appmatic\Database;

require '../vendor/autoload.php';
require '../app/controllers/AppmaticController.php';
require '../app/utils/ErrorHandler.php';
include '../app/config/constants.php';

$config = require '../app/config/config.php';
$app = new \Slim\App($config);

require '../app/routes.php';

$container = $app->getContainer();

$container['view'] = function () {
    return new \Slim\Views\PhpRenderer('../app/views/');
};

$container['AppmaticController'] = function ($container) {
    return new Controllers\AppmaticController($container);
};

$app->run();
```

/app/routes.php

```
<?php
$app->post('/send-mail', 'AppmaticController:sendMail');
```

Server: localhost, Apache2
OS: Ubuntu 16.04
PHP 7.0

Comment: Clear or disable your browser cache, make a "deep reload". Check if you _really_ save the changes at the correct location.

Comment: I cleared 1 week cache and I tried from several explorers. I always use deep reload and, of course, I save the file :D

Comment: I asked if you save it in the right location. If you really make changes to the executed script, then they are picked up. So the question is where your changes go to.

Comment: Sorry, I was wrong, the file is in the correct location. It worked fine the first time I test it, but when I saved it, stops changing.

Comment: Can you be more specific? i.e. "I change X from A  to B but in all browsers I check I still get A".

Comment: Nothing we can say. Either you have a cached result or you save your changes in the wrong location. First check your http servers access and error log file, then examine the actual request made my opening the browsers development console and checking the result.

Comment: That's the last log from apache 
```[Wed Oct 05 15:53:18.691443 2016] [core:notice] [pid 9755] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'```, when I started it

Comment: And whatever I change, it stays static. I can remove every line and print an echo and it send the email correctly

Comment: I tried to remove the ```$app->post('/send-mail', 'AppmaticController:sendMail');``` and it stills working!!

Comment: Can you `die()` in `public_html/index.php?

Comment: Yes, if I put die() before ```$app->run()``` don't work anything.

Comment: Can you please add `die('hello')` to `AppmaticController::sendMail` method as the very first line? Just to make sure.

Comment: Don't make anything, if it is not there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PHPStorm, the IDE I use, turns mad. When I tried to close it, I realized I couldn't close it and when I tried to open the project, there's no changes made so that's the problem.

But when I opened the file before with Sublime changes were effective so I think that's a bug with PHPStorm or something similar.

Thanks everyone who tried to help :)

Answer (score 0):

Well, try restarting the web server :)
As you are not specifying which system you are on I'm going to explain 2 situations:

**Windows**
Go to the XAMPP screen and click "Stop" , once stapped hit "start" for the web server entry.

** Linux **
Based on your distro run either of these:

- sudo service apache2 restart
- sudo systemctl restart httpd.service

**Also, I noticed a \ in your code that shouldn't be there, try removing that.**

```
$mail = new \PHPMailer();
```

Should look like:

```
$mail = new PHPMailer();
```

Comment: That `\\` is perfectly fine. It indicates a namespace.

Comment: I use Ubuntu 16.04 and I restarted the server twice

Comment: Restarting the http server is not required to pick up file changes.

Comment: My bad, I didn't notice the OS in your initial question.
Are you absolutely sure the file gets written? Just cat it out and see if it changed :)

Comment: Yes, the file was written and has all required permssions

Comment: Are you using namespaces and did you mean to put that \ before the new phpmailer? Or is this the example from github with modified values? :)

Also, do html files reload?

Comment: I'm using namespaces in my app so I put it to mark the root namespace: http://php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.php

Comment: Right, just checking everything ;)

Do html files reload?

Comment: Yes, all is reloading fine except this .php for any reason

Comment: Try adding an echo with some text as the FIRST line, also enable error reporting by adding: error_reporting(E_ALL);

Lastly run you code through a check: http://phpcodechecker.com/ or post more if it on stack so we can have a look :)

Comment: I added the echo but don't show anything... This is a controller for Slim Framework, there is not more code... I can post the Controller and the route to see how it works if you want.

Comment: Please do. Adding as much information as you can is always a good idea.

Comment: Weird, there don't seem to be any problems in the code.....
Try this... Make it write out to a file (first lines of code) and "run" it, see if the file gets written, might be a browser issue??
also
I know it sounds weird but try removing and reinstalling the server?

should be: apt-get remove --purge apache2/httpd but I might be wrong, haven't used ubuntu in a while (arch fan myself).